# R Shiny Radio Buttons not Updating with updateRadioButtons

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on a quiz type program in Shiny, which needs to have radio buttons that update with answers from a table.  I have the code below, but the radio buttons don't update, and the answers remain 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 despite changing questions.  Any ideas on why this might be happening, and what would fix this?

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("numberchoice",label = "Choose an image", choices = c(1:6), selected = 1)
  ,
  imageOutput("image")
  ,
  radioButtons("answerchoice", "Answers", choices = c(2:6))

)

server <- function(input,output,session) {
  answers <- read.csv("~/Answers.csv")
  questions <- read.csv("~/Answers.csv")
  output$image <- renderImage(list(src = paste("~",".png", sep = "")
  ,contentType = "image/png", alt = "Face"),deleteFile = FALSE)
  eventReactive(input$numberchoice,{updateRadioButtons(session,"answerchoice",choices = questions[input$numberchoice,2:6])})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: the `selectInput` needs to be built with `UIOutput()`. Then you can use `renderUI()` with inputs from the UI Output that will be in the `server` function. Complicated, I know. See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html)

Comment: @RobertMc Okay, I've done that. I now just have the problem that it gives the answer choices as the headings of the "questions" chart, rather than the actual values in the chart. It seems to me that "questions[input$numberchoice,2:6]" is returning the headings (which I've named A through E) instead of the actual answer choices which are numbers in the csv that is being read

Comment: Hmm, could you update your question with some sample data that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @RobertMc The [`updateXXX`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/update-input-demo.html) functions make it possible to update inputs  without rerendering the corresponding input element. They are shipped with shiny and therefore save to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `eventReactive` with `observeEvent`. The following code works for me.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("numberchoice", label = "Choose an image", choices = 1:6, selected = 1),
  radioButtons("answerchoice", "Answers", choices = 1:6 )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$numberchoice,{
    updateRadioButtons(session, "answerchoice",
      choices = letters[1:input$numberchoice])})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It seems like `eventReactive` didn't trigger so `updateRadioButtons` was not the problem.